# how to add button action in PSPDFKit

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, pdf, pspdfkit

I am using PSPDFKit and wondering how to add button programmatically on same pages (say page 21 of pdf) and when I click that button, I should go to some another view controller where I will have data according to the page number.

e.g. I have buttons on all pages and if I click on page 21 button 1, I should get re-directed to new view controller and there I will be having label which will say page 21.

Any idea/ suggestion how to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the PSCButtonPDFViewController in PSPDFCatalog to see how to add buttons to a PSPDFPageView. Then it's simple to add a custom target that does what you want.